# When should you start potty training your children?

Tags: teaching, potty-training

I have a 16 month old and she has been taking her diaper off when its messy. She also seems to know when she has to go.

What's the typical age that kids get potty trained?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a typical age. They will let you know when they are ready.

Now I would make sure you help her know that going on the potty is a very good thing!

[The Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/potty-training/CC00060) has a good set of questions you should ask yourself before starting:

> - Does your child seem interested in the potty chair or toilet, or in wearing underwear?
> - Can your child understand and follow basic directions?
> - Can your child ask simple questions?
> - Does your child stay dry for periods of two hours or longer during the day? Does he or she wake from naps dry?
> - Does your child have fairly predictable bowel movements?
> - Does your child tell you through words, facial expressions or posture when he or she needs to go?
> - Is your child uncomfortable in wet or dirty diapers?
> - Can your child pull down his or her pants and pull them up again?
>
> If you answered mostly yes, your child may be ready for potty training. If you answered mostly no, you may want to wait a while.

Don't get discouraged if she loses interest in potty training. It happened with my son.